# I can't upgrade to Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: upgrade

I keep getting this error when I try to upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to 22.10

```
W:This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details., 
W:Conflicting distribution: https://pkg.fig.io/apt jammy InRelease (expected jammy but got stable), 
E:Repository 'https://pkg.fig.io/apt jammy InRelease' changed its 'Codename' value from 'jammy' to 'stable'
```

Comment: Why did you add the pkg.fig.io repo to your system?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve this upgrade error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321764/how-to-solve-this-upgrade-error)